# Como salvar dados de requisição em sessionStorage ou Cookies?

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

Estou desenvolvendo um chat com WebSocket e nele existe a lista de usuários, quando eu clico em um determinado usuário inicia-se uma conversa apenas com aquele usuário, minha dúvida é a seguinte: ao clicar no usuário para começar uma nova conversa é feita uma requisição que retorna todas as minhas conversas com esse usuário (utilizando ajax()), se eu clicar novamente na lista para começar uma nova conversa com esse mesmo usuário, ele novamente faz a requisição das mensagens. Gostaria de salvar os dados retornados em um Cookie ou em sessionStorage do HTML5 para que se eu clicar novamente neste usuário para iniciar uma conversa não precise fazer novamente uma requisição.

ps.: Ao clicar em um usuário para iniciar uma conversa ele adiciona um html() com as mensagens retornadas via ajax() de um arquivo PHP na div onde ficam as mensagens. 
Se eu clicar em iniciar uma conversa com outro usuário gostaria que o procedimento fosse o mesmo.

Código jQuery:

```
function add_janelas(id, nome){
    var nome_add = '<p class="nome-informacoes '+id+'" id="'+id+'">'+nome+'</p>';
    var content_msg = '<div id="jan_'+id+'" class="janela_conv '+id+'"></div>';
    $('.informacoes').html(nome_add);
    $('.message_box').html(content_msg);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var janelas = new Array();
    var users = new Array();
    var comecar = $(".comecar");

comecar.click(function(){

    users = [];
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var nome = $(this).attr('title');

    add_janelas(id, nome);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'sys/chat.php',
        data: 'acao='+'atualizar'+'&id='+id,
        success: function(html){
            $(".janela_conv").html(html);
        }
    });

    });
});
```

Código PHP (chat.php):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once '../config.php';
    require_once ("../classes/BD.class.php");
    BD::conn();

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

    $acao = $_POST['acao'];

    switch ($acao) {    
        case 'atualizar':
            $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';

            $select = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM mensagem WHERE id_de = ? AND id_para = ? OR id_de = ? AND id_para = ?");
            $select->execute(array($_SESSION['id_user'], $id, $id, $_SESSION['id_user']));

            $mensagem = '';
            while($fetch = $select->fetchObject()){
                $nome = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT nome FROM usuarios WHERE id = ?");
                $nome->execute(array($fetch->id_de));
                $remetente = $nome->fetchObject();

                $mensagem .= "<div class='mensagem'><span class='user_name' nome=" . $remetente->nome . " style=''>" . $remetente->nome . "</span> : <pre><span class='user_messag'>" . $fetch->msg . "</span></pre></div>";

                echo $mensagem;
            }
        break;
    }
?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terá que gravar em `localStorage` o valor que recebe quando abre a primeira vez, quando houver outro clique, você vai verificar se o localStorage desse janela ja existe, se sim mostra esse html em vez do html que vem do php:

```
comecar.click(function(){

    users = [];
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var nome = $(this).attr('title');
    var locStorage = window.localStorage;
    var hasConvo = locStorage.getItem(nome);
    add_janelas(id, nome);
    if (!hasConvo) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'sys/chat.php',
            data: 'acao='+'atualizar'+'&id='+id,
            success: function(html){
                locStorage.setItem(nome,html);
                $(".janela_conv").html(html);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $('.janela_conv').html(hasConvo);
    }

});
```

Comment: e se existir uma nova requisição? Tipo, se existir uma nova mensagem como fazer para ele guardar no localStorage a partir do momento da nova mensagem?

Comment: @DavidDamasceno teria que ter mais informação de como o seu javascript funciona, na tua pergunta só mostras o "começar"; Mas, sabendo que __podes gravar Objectos__ em localStorage por meio de `JSON.stringify({})` é uma questão de organização e propriedades :)

Comment: não consegui entender muito bem a lógica para fazer com que ele faça uma nova requisição se existirem novos dados, poderia me explicar?

Comment: Eu poderia ir salvando no localstorage quando der um append das mensagens?